# How do i perform a clone of html form fields and submit them to my backend in vuejs

Tags: php, vue.js

i am trying to build an online cv to allow users add more "work experience" details to a larger form. i want them to be able to click a button and a new "work experience" field comes up and they can add more details.

Comment: So, what do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add **workExperiences** array in data
2. add a new object in workExperiences array to add a new work experience
3. use `v-for="(experience, index) in workExperiences"` to show input fields
4. add `` :name="`workExperiences[${index}][company]`" `` to input if you will submit the form.

Full example:

[image: Edit Vue Dynamic form fields]

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <form>
      <h1>Work experiences</h1>
      <div class="work-experiences">

        <div class="form-row" v-for="(experience, index) in workExperiences" :key="index">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Company</label>
            <input v-model="experience.company" :name="`workExperiences[${index}][company]`" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input v-model="experience.title" :name="`workExperiences[${index}][title]`" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <button @click="addExperience" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Add experience</button>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <div class="form-group">
        <button @click="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "App",

  data: () => ({
    workExperiences: [
      {
        company: "Foxconn",
        title: "Engineer"
      },
      {
        company: "Cherri Tech",
        title: "Software Engineer"
      }
    ]
  }),

  methods: {
    addExperience () {
      this.workExperiences.push({
        company: '',
        title: ''
      })
    },

    submit () {
      const data = {
        workExperiences: this.workExperiences
      }
      alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
    }
  }
};
</script>
```